# Can I release a grapple then grapple another target with Bigbys hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, forced-movement

First turn i gapple a target with Bigbys hand. On my next turn can I move the hand 30 feet, release the target, and grapple another target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Releasing a grapple requires none of your actions so **yes**.

Answer (score 4):

The only potential glitch in this plan is that normally if a grappler moves while dragging a grappled creature, it gets only half movement.  So you would have to check with your DM to see if that limitation applies to the Bigby's Hand spell.  If the DM says that it doesn't apply, then your plan works; if the limitation does apply, then on your next turn you can move the hand only 15 feet while dragging the grappled subject, then release the target, and grapple another target.

Comment: The hand can normally be moved 60 feet, so I think this is already taken into account.

Comment: Ah, OK, then yes, I'd agree that the planned course of action is valid.